# How remove the specific value from map in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am Beginner in flutter, learning map concept. I am confusing map methods. How to delete a specific value from a map?

for example:

```
Map data = {
  "studet1": {"name": "ajk", "age": "22", "place": "delhi"},
  "studet2": {"name": "akmal", "age": "25", "place": "up"}
};
```

I want to delete the "name" from "student1".

Answer (score 5):

`data` is a nested `map`, which means that it has another `map` within the key of `student1`.

You can use the [`.remove`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.6/dart-core/Map/remove.html) method to remove a key within a map:

> Removes `key` and its associated value, if present, from the map.

```dart
void main() {
  Map data ={
    "student1":{
      "name" : "ajk",
      "age":"22",
      "place":"delhi"

    },
    "student2":{
      "name" : "akmal",
      "age":"25",
      "place":"up"

    }
  };
  
  data['student1'].remove('name');
  print(data);
}
```

Prints:

```
{student1: {age: 22, place: delhi}, student2: {name: akmal, age: 25, place: up}}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove only student1 name

Just use  `data['student1'].remove('name');`

Or if you want to remove all  students name use the bleow method

```
   Map data = {
      "studet1": {"name": "ajk", "age": "22", "place": "delhi"},
      "studet2": {"name": "akmal", "age": "25", "place": "up"}
    };
    for (int i = 0; i <= data.length - 1; i++) {
      data[data.keys.elementAt(i)].remove('name');
    }
```

The output will be

```
{student1: {age: 22, place: delhi}, student2: {age: 25, place: up}}
```